# Can the inverse of a permutation be the same as itself?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

For example, I have the following permutation:

P(3 4 1 2 5)

When I calculate the inverse of this permutation, I get the same result: (3 4 1 2 5)

Am I doing the calculation incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are doing it fine. Those kind of permutations are called **Involutions**. If you write the cycle decomposition of those you will see that cycles are just composed by $1$ or $2$ elements. In your case $$34125=(13)(24)(5).$$